# Mac .flac player that organizes folder structure? Can Songbird write to a ntfs drive?

Tags: macos, ntfs, media-player, flac, songbird

I have a bunch of music in .flac format on my pc.  I would like to put that music on an external drive which I can access from both my Mac and PC at work.

I have the drive formatted in NTFS using MacFUSE and NTFS-3G drivers.  Through Finder I write to the drive fine.  If I go to Show Info I see that I have custom access.

I am trying to use Songbird to play said .flac files.  I have Folder Management turned on.  When I try to import to Library it errors out and says make sure drive exists and is writable.  This seems like a permissions issue but I do not see how I could change them.

If anyone knows of a good .flac player for the mac that also organizes folder structures like iTunes please let me know.  This and the ability to write to a NTFS drive is what I am looking for.

Comment: Players do not "write to NTFS drives". Only the operating system (OS X) does.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running songbird from the terminal with sudo? It may be that songbird doesn't have permission to write to the hard drive.

Comment: You mean just launching songbird from terminal using sudo?

Comment: Yeah, I've had similar problems with songbird in Linux, and launching it with sudo solved them. I don't know if it will work for you, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

For write support of NFTS on OS X you have to install [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net) to mount the filesystem properly.